# Usage of declare OAuth2 in manifest file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Recently, I am working on creating a chrome extension, and we can declare **OAuth2 object with client_id and scopes** in the manifest file.

After that, when I am setting up the OAuth consent screen in the Google Console, I also found out that we can include the scopes that we want.

I want to ask what's the differences or usage between both of them.

Answer (score 0):

In oauth2 scopes define the limit of authorization you are requesting from a user.  Remember authentication is login, oauth2 is authorization. Your application is requesting authorization to access a users data.

Each method in an api will require different set of authorization in order to access the data.

Method which only request access to read data like a users profile, will typically only require read only access.

Methods which require access to write to the users data say adding an event in the users calendar will require write access.

The following is a list  [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)

Comment: Superb, thank you for the explanation, I wish I could ask one more question, would scopes inside the OAuth consent screen will clash with the scopes inside the manifest file.

Comment: They should be the same.  What ever scopes your application is requesting should appear on the consent screen.    Note: i am not a JavaScript expert by any means.